# expression must have class type but it has type "double *const"

Tags: c++

I am following Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++". In chapter 18.3, we are to make a method that takes in a vector by reference:

```
using namespace std;

class vector {
private:
    size_t sz;
    double* elem;

public:
    vector(int s)
        :sz(s), elem(new double[s])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) elem[i] = 0;
    } // constructor

    vector(initializer_list<double> lst)
        :sz{ lst.size() }, elem{ new double[sz] }
    {
        copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem);
    }

    vector(const vector& arg); // vector by reference (question is here)

    int size() const { return sz; }; // the current size

    double get(int n) const { return elem[n]; } // read
    void set(int n, double v) { elem[n] = v; }  // write

    ~vector()
    {
        delete[] elem;
    } //destructor
};


vector::vector(const vector& arg)
    :sz{arg.sz}, elem{new double[arg.sz]}
{
    std::copy(arg.elem, arg.elem.sz, elem);
}
```

I see an error:

> expression must have class type but it has type "double *const"

I have copied Bjarne's code exactly. I am not sure why it's not working.

Comment: `using namespace std;` *might* mess up, becuase `std::vector` exists. Try to remove that line first and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Also, please provide full error message and mark which line of code is it related to (with a comment or something).

Comment: Typo by you or Bjarne? `arg.elem.sz` should be `arg.elem + sz` in your `std::copy` or simply `std::copy_n(arg.elem, sz, elem);`

Comment: It's a typo by Bjarne then. I can see here in the book it says "arg.elem.sz" and not "arg.elem + sz". Thank you @ Ted Lyngmo.

Comment: When including `using namespace std;` line, compiler might easily get confused whether you mean `std::vector` or your own `vector`, because both names are in the global namespace. But yeah, the typo pointed out by Ted seems to be the real culprit (which doesn't mean `using namespace std;` won't cause issues in the future).

Comment: Why not create your own namespace just to be on the safe side.

Comment: It works fine if you put the copy constructor inline: https://onlinegdb.com/Juq7ul2Qy  When the copy constructor is outside the error I get is "reference to vector is ambiguous" which means it is the `using namespace std;`  You can see it working without the `using namespace std;` here: https://onlinegdb.com/GKTv0Hr5h